# CORS Blocked My Redirection When Trying To Authorize With OAuth

Tags: node.js, express, cors, shopify, shopify-api

I am building an external Shopify application. I have a register menu that when I click on register button should send a get request to my server on ('/auth?shop=myShopName.myshopify.com) and then on this, the authentification will begin with beginAuth Shopify api method. At the end of the method, I have a res.redirect to the link returned by beginAuh which is (https://myShopName.myshopify.com/admin/oath/authorize?client_id=*******&scope=write_products%2Cwrite...) but I get a CORS error :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myShopName.myshopify.com/admin/oath/authorize?client_id=*******&scope=write_products%2C
write...' (redirected from *'http://localhost:3000/auth?shop=myShopName.myshopify.com') from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

What can I do to solve this? Thanks all!

Comment: It seems that you make the request to `/auth?shop=myShopName.myshopify.com` in your client-side Javascript code, via `fetch`, but you must instead load this URL in the browser. Then the redirection to `https://myshopname.myshopify.com/admin/oath/authorize?client_id=*******&scope=write_products%2Cwrite...` will also happen in the browser. Only by interacting with the browser can the user authenticate.

Comment: With using window.open(link) ?

Comment: What I trying really to do is when the user installs the app on the shopify, I save this on my server side to have not to request app installation each time...

Comment: You should describe the whole user onboarding process in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Shopify offers clear instructions on how to authorize an App. If you follow the instructions they offer you will be presented with a store name and an authentification token to save in your database to re-use. There are no CORS issues if you follow this pattern, and you don't have to request app installation over and over again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. When the sign up button is clicked, I make a get request to my /auth?shop=${shopName} and then use the Shopify beginAuth api method. At the end, I am trying to redirect to the link generated by this method ```https://myShopName.myshopify.com/admin/oath/authorize?client_id=*******&scope=write_products%2C
write...```...